# "data type not understood" when appending DataFrames

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, append

So I'm starting with a blank DataFrame, pulling a bunch of new dataFrames from SQL statements based on a list of table names, and then appending each one to the starting dataFrame.
ex:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for name in tableslist:
    perT = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT FROM myschema.{0} WHERE username = '{1}'.format(name,user),engine)
    df1 = df1.append(perT)
```

That returns the error: `data type not understood` in the terminal. I'm positive that it is caused by the append line (I've checked with print statements). What could cause that? It's possible for perT to be a table with no rows. Is that an issue? I've tried printing out the head of each table, and still can't determine what is causing that error/failure.

Comment: Are you sure your queries give you what you're expecting? Try running them separately, individually.

Comment: Try running `mysql` query separately, collect query output a text/csv file and then adding to `df`. That may help pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that with older versions of pandas this can happen with when date fields are present in the dataframe (specifically `datetime64` variants). In the past I've used a number of workarounds (see below), hard to know exactly what can help you without seeing the data.

1. Cast all date fields into pandas timestamps (`df[col_name].apply(pd.Timestamp)`).
2. Cast all date fields into strings (`df[col_name].astype(str)`).
3. Your initial dataframe is an empty dataframe. Instead of trying to append a non-empty dataframe to an empty one, set the initial one to equal the first non-empty dataframe, and then keep appending.

   ```
   if df1.empty:
       df1 = perT
   else:
       df1 = df1.append(perT)
   ```
4. Upgrade pandas :)

Comment: I did steps 3 and 4. I believe the error was coming from trying to append empty data frames (either to full ones or append full ones to empty ones)! much obliged